# Inner join with table that does not contain any record fails?

Tags: postgresql

I have query in which I have applied inner join, it works fine if the joining table on right side has some records, but inner joins return nothing when joining table has 0 (zero) records, and I understand it bcz it has nothing to join on.

**I want the records from tbl11 if record has status=1 in tbl11 or if that record exist in tbl12 then it must have status=1, if tbl12.status=0, then that record is not needed.**

Table structure

```
create table tbl11
(
  tbl11_id serial primary key,
  name character varying,
  status integer
)

insert into tbl11(name, status) values('Tony',1),
('Jony',1),
('Sneha',1),
('Aakriti',0)


create table tbl12
(
  tbl12_id serial primary key,
  tbl11_id integer,
  name character varying,
  status integer
)
```

Here is what, I have tried till now

```
select t1.tbl11_id, t1.name, t1.status from tbl11 t1
inner join tbl12 t2 on t1.tbl11_id = t2.tbl11_id or t1.tbl11_id !=t2.tbl11_id
where t1.status=1 and t2.status=1
```

It gives no output as tbl12 doesn't have any data.

Then I read about case in postgres and tried this

```
select case 
    when 
        select exists (select 1 from tbl12) 
    Then 
        select t1.tbl11_id, t1.name, t1.status from tbl11 t1
        inner join tbl12 t2 on t1.tbl11_id = t2.tbl11_id or t1.tbl11_id !=t2.tbl11_id
        where t1.status=1 and t2.status=2
    else
        select tbl11_id, name, status from tbl11 where status=1
```

But it gives error as

```
    ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 3:   select exists (select 1 from tbl12)
```

Comment: I have a real hard time following the logic you are trying to implement. I think it would be better if you showed us some sample data and the expected output based on that data. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. Or even better set up a little [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12) with the table definitions and sample data.

Comment: Ok I understand. I have modified the question with simple use case. Please have a look. @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 0):

this is the simple query

```
select * from tbl11 where status=1 and tbl11_id not in (select tbl11_id from tbl12 where status=0);
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gNWw3qizFzXX5nkYoJBNTm/0)

Comment: Thanks! Missed the simplicity silly mistake from my side.

Comment: For error in your last Query Just put the condition of `CASE WHEN` in `()`. 
`case when (select exists (select 1 from tbl12) )  Then`